# ExpressJS AngularJS POST

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm learning AngularJS and I want to know how to correctly wire it with Node with ExpressJS.

This is my controller:

```
app.controller('view1Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.sub = function(desc) {
        console.log(desc);
        $http.post('/view1', desc).
        then(function(response) {
            console.log("posted successfully");
        }).catch(function(response) {
            console.error("error in posting");
        })
    }
});
```

And this is my server.js:

```
app.post('/view1', function(req, res) {
    console.log(res.desc);
    res.end();
});
```

I have not used body-parser. I don't get how body-parser is used to get the form values from the html when I am using a function in controller. Does the values got from the html on clicking submit when using body-parser or does the values are got from the function on which I am passing the form values as arguments. Please tell me how it is done .

**EDIT:** this is my html:

```
<form>
      <input type="text" ng-model="desc" placeholder="Enter desc" />
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sub(desc)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT 2:**
full server.js code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser= require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);

app.use(express.static(path.normalize(__dirname + '/')));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing       application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.get('/main', function(req, res) {
    var name = 'MyNameFromServer';
    res.send(name);
});

app.post('/view1', function(req, res) {
    console.log(res.body.desc);
    res.end();
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**EDIT 3:** 
Edited Controller app.js

```
app.controller('view1Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {    
    $scope.sub = function() {
        console.log($scope.formData);
        $http.post('/view1', $scope.formData).
        success(function(data) {
            console.log("posted successfully");
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.error("error in posting");
        })
    };
});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The body-parser module for Node.js (Express) can get every data from your form post into a single object called `req.body`, so if you have a `$scope` object to define your form data you can inject directly that to have the same properties copied on req.body:

Angular:

```
app.controller('view1Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sub = function() {
        $http.post('/view1',$scope.formData).
        then(function(response) {
            console.log("posted successfully");
        }).catch(function(response) {
            console.error("error in posting");
        })
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
      <input type="text" ng-model="formData.desc" placeholder="Enter desc" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="formData.title" placeholder="Enter title" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sub()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now when you submit it via `$http.post('/view1', $scope.formData)`you will get the same object, for example:

```
app.post('/view1', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.desc);
    res.end();
});
```

Instead having an ng-click on the submit button, you could also use `ng-submit`in the form element like this:

```
<form ng-submit="sub()">
```

Comment: What about the ng-click of the button ? should it pass the desc once again or should I just have to call it with out passing anything ?

Comment: You don't need it, you have the `$scope` I'm updating the answer.

Comment: After all the modifications , it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'desc' of undefined..

Comment: I actually get that error in the node server.! It says desc is undefined.

Comment: Do a `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: So you didn't add `body-parser` to your project, it could be more useful if you update your question with the server side code too. I won't comment it anymore.

Comment: I have added the body-parser in the server code. Anyways i'll add the code in the evening as I am in my workplace right now.

Comment: Did you changed the angular part to submit `$scope.formData` instead `desc`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81997/discussion-between-vichu-and-michelem).

Answer (score 8):

First of all you should be aware of two global variable `req` and `res`.

when you hit post request `req.body` catches the request from `http` and `body-parser` extracts the raw content from post request.

```
app.post('/view1', function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body.desc);
 res.end();
});
```

before using it you must include

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

and include middleware as

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing       application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

more about `middleware`, `req` and `res` please refer to

http://expressjs.com/4x

Comment: So in my html , there is no need for me to pass the desc variable ? should I just call the sub() ?

Comment: of course angular's two-way data-binding does it for you. when you define ng-model= 'desc' in view you can use it in your controller with $scope.desc.

Comment: yeah no need to pass it, $scope object contains all the scope variable within the territory you defined your controller.

Comment: and does req.body contain only the values inside that particular form ? also can you add the controller in your answer . I still don't get it .

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.json())` was it for me! Oh man that was frustrating.